# How to find text without html tag and wrapp it with a p elment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code. I would like to find and replace the text without HTML tags and wrap it inside a `p` element using jQuery. Is there a way to reach my goal?

```
<div class="col span_12_of_12 firstDiv">
  <h2>My tasks</h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
  </ul>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
</div>
```

Comment: what should be the output markup?

Comment: find? and replace?

Comment: I think OP is referring to the 2 `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr` that aren't encapsulated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this you need to find the child textNodes and wrap them in a `<p>` tag. To do that you can use `contents()` and `filter()` then `wrap()`, like this:

```js
$('.col').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent.trim();
}).wrap('<p />');
```

```css
p { border: 1px solid #C00; } /* only used to make the output obvious */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col span_12_of_12 firstDiv">
  <h2>My tasks</h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
  </ul>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
</div>
```